# Understanding UICollectionViewFlowLayout sizing and spacing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am working with a `UICollectionView` using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and have some difficulties to understand item sizing an spacing. I know that there several methods to adapt sizing and spacing (using the delegate methods, overriding FlowLayout, etc.). **However without understanding the logic behind these values in the first place, it is quite hard to adapt them properly.**

The following results have been created a default `UICollectionViewController` with a default `UICollectionViewCell` without any subclasses. Only the following settings haven been made:

- Specified the cell size to be 200 x 200 in IB
- Placed a Label inside the cell and centered in vertically and horizontal

[image]

Code:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class MyViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
            layout.sectionInsetReference = .fromContentInset
            return layout
        }
        
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    /*func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        var width = view.frame.width
        return CGSize(width: collectionVw.frame.size.height, height: collectionVw.frame.size.height)
    }*/
}
```

Using different values for `layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5` creates results I do not understand:

[image]

- <s>Why are the items 50 x 50px in size? I know that one can use `...sizeForItemAt` to specify explicit dimensions. However, setting the size in IB should also work, shouldn't it? Why is the IB size of 200 x 200px ignored? Why 50x50, is this the default size or where is this specified?</s> Solved in the answer by @Larme
- I know that `minimumInteritemSpacing` does not set the explicit spacing but only a **minimum**. However, how is the value computed?
- Why is the a spacing of `7.5px` for a value of 5? Why result values 10-25 result all in the same a spacing of `26.5px`?

**So: How exactly are sizes and spacing computed here?**

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple questions (not really recommended), I'll answer what I can do.

> Why are the items 50 x 50px in size? I know that one can use ...sizeForItemAt to specify explicit dimensions. However, setting the size in IB should also work, shouldn't it? Why is the IB size of 200 x 200px ignored? Why 50x50, is this the default size or where is this specified?

You are doing:

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Where layout is newly created.
You aren't using the previous settings in InterfaceBuilder, you are overriding them by code.
And your created for `layout`, its `itemSize` hasn't been set. And from the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617711-itemsize), if not set, it's 50x50.

> Why are the items aligned to the left for these values and distribued evenly of the complete width for value of 30?

Are you sure about that? Default Layout (meaning, not a inherited from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`) will behave like paragraphs styling.
I'll take the horizontal layout (same logic can be applied in vertical, but analogy with text paragraphs would be strange):

If you have multilines text, the first line would take as much width as possible, but the last line will not, keeping it "left" aligned.

For your spacing calculations, according to the doc of [`minimumInterItemSpacing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617706-minimuminteritemspacing?language=objc):

> For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same row. For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same column. **This spacing is used to compute how many items can fit in a single line, but after the number of items is determined, the actual spacing may possibly be adjusted upward.**

But, I'm wondering, what would happen if you override `viewDidLayoutSubview()`, and call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout(); collectionView.collectionViewLayout?.prepareLayout()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You are absolutely right about the 50x50px default size. About the other questions: I am a 100% sure `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is used and now subclass (just as in the code shown in the question) and it behaves as you can see in the image: "left aligned" for values up to 25, paragraph style for value 30. Why is this? About the calculation: I know the information from the docs you quoted. However, "...the actual spacing may possibly be adjusted" does not realy explain in detail how the spacing is computed, does it?

Comment: Do you have a Sample project?

Comment: Just prepared one, but how/where could I upload it? It is really jus a new project, replace the initial view controller in storyboard with a `UICollectionViewController`, and use the code shown in my question.

Comment: GitHub can be fine. Note that also if you rotate your simulator where you took the screenshot, does it take as you think the whole width (for your last sample?)

Comment: Rotation was a good hint: Spacing stays the same (does not use complete width in landscape). So it seems that that using "complete width" is just a coincidence for `minimumInteritemSpacing = 30`. However, the main question remains: "how exactly are spacings calculated"

Answer (score 1):

As you've already learned from **Larme**, your Storyboard layout is ignored because you create a new layout.

When the collection view lays out its cells, it says:

- is there an `.itemSize`?
- no, ask the cell for its size
- cell returns size of `.zero` (your cell has no constraints affecting its size)
- so, use the `.estimatedItemSize`

In your case, you set `layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` which means *"use the default of `(50, 50)`"*.

***"So: How exactly are sizes and spacing computed here?"***

Well, let's take a look at some more cells.

We'll use 6 sections...

- 0 & 1 will have `.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0`
- 2 & 3 will have `.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0`
- 4 & 5 will have `.minimumInteritemSpacing = 30.0`

and we'll alternate between 3 and 7 items per section. Looks like this:

[image]

The answer is now pretty obvious - the collection view calculates how many **total** cells will fit (not how many cells are in the section) - based on cell-width plus minSpacing - and then increases the spacing for a "perfect fit."

So, assuming a collection view frame width of `320.0` and section insets of `20.0` on each side, we can calculate the adjusted item spacing:

**min item spacing = 5.0**

```
// CellWidth + MinSpacing
50.0 + 5.0 = 55.0

// collViewWidth - sectionInsets
320.0 - (20.0 + 20.0) = 280.0

// spacing is only BETWEEN cells, not at end, so
//  add spacing
280.0 + 5.0 = 285.0

// how many cells will fit?
285.0 / 55.0 = 5.1818181818181817

// can't have a "partial-cell" so 
floor(285.0 / 55.0) = 5.0
numCells = 5

// width of 5 cells
50.0 * numCells = 250.0

// "extra" space
280.0 - 250.0 = 30.0

// with 5 cells fitting, we have 4 "spaces" (numCells - 1)
30.0 / 4.0 = 7.5

actual spacing = 7.5
```

---

**min item spacing = 10.0**

```
// CellWidth + MinSpacing
50.0 + 10.0 = 60.0

// collViewWidth - sectionInsets
320.0 - (20.0 + 20.0) = 280.0

// spacing is only BETWEEN cells, not at end, so
//  add spacing
280.0 + 10.0 = 290.0

// how many cells will fit?
290.0 / 60.0 = 4.833333333333333

// can't have a "partial-cell" so 
floor(290.0 / 60.0) = 4.0
numCells = 4

// width of 4 cells
50.0 * 4.0 = 200.0

// "extra" space
280.0 - 200.0 = 80.0

// with 4 cells fitting, we have 3 "spaces"
80.0 / 3.0 = 26.666666 (rounded to 26.5 on @2x device scale)

actual spacing = 26.5
```

---

**min item spacing = 30.0**

```
// CellWidth + MinSpacing
50.0 + 30.0 = 80.0

// collViewWidth - sectionInsets
320.0 - (20.0 + 20.0) = 280.0

// spacing is only BETWEEN cells, not at end, so
//  add spacing
280.0 + 30.0 = 310.0

// how many cells will fit?
310.0 / 80.0 = 3.875

// can't have a "partial-cell" so 
floor(250.0 / 80.0) = 3.0
numCells = 3

// width of 3 cells
50.0 * 3.0 = 150.0

// "extra" space
280.0 - 150.0 = 130.0

// with 3 cells fitting, we have 2 "spaces"
130.0 / 2.0 = 65.0

actual spacing = 65.0
```

---

Here is some example code to see that result...

Simple cell with centered label:

```
class CenterLabelCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .light)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Example view controller:

```
class CollViewSpacingVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let itemSpaces: [CGFloat] = [
        5.0, 10.0, 30.0,
    ]
    
    let sectionColors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed,   .systemRed.withAlphaComponent(0.5),
        .systemGreen, .systemGreen.withAlphaComponent(0.5),
        .systemBlue,  .systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.5),
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
            layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            layout.sectionInset = .init(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 20.0)
            return layout
        }
    
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(CenterLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return itemSpaces[section / 2]
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sectionColors.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section % 2 == 0 ? 3 : 7
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! CenterLabelCell
        cell.label.text = "\(Int(itemSpaces[indexPath.section / 2]))"
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = sectionColors[indexPath.section]
        return cell
    }
    
}
```